# pass argument to function using addEventListener

Tags: javascript

i am quite new to addEventListener method.i am trying to pass argument to function using addEventListener .but it is not worining.why i can't passing the string "2a" using addEventListener method?it will be very helpful if you explain this problem to me.thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mm{
width:100px;
height:60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function lister(){
document.getElementById("tab1").addEventListener("click",myfunc("2a"));
}
function myfunc(str){
alert(str);
}
window.onload=listener;
</script>
<table style="border:1px solid black;padding:2px;margin:2px 2px 2px 2px;">
<tr><td class="mm" id="tab1">this is it</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mm" id="tab2">no tis titt</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to do that is to use an anonymous function

```
function lister(){
    document.getElementById("tab1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        myfunc("2a");
    }, false);
}
```