# Pass Argument In Event Listener Function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass an argument to the function that is being called inside of the event listener.  The code below shows what I want to do however it is not letting me do it conventionally.  What is a workaround to this?

HTML code :

```
<button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
```

JavaScript code :

```
<script>
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener( "click",btnClick(5) );
function btnClick(argument)
{
console.log("Button clicked with argument : " + argument);
}
</script>
```

Console should read :

```
Button clicked with argument : 5
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an anonymous function

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener( "click", function() {
    btnClick(5);
}, false );
```

If you need to keep the value of `this` you can use call or apply

```
btnClick.call(this, 5);
```

Comment: Why do you keep answering those questions? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/q/23548403/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23005695/218196

Comment: @FelixKling - Yeah, I noticed the dupe. I have no idea, I just sometimes answer without thinking, other times I instantly remember a dupe and tag etc. Depends !

Comment: @FelixKling - Maybe I can blame dementia ?