# Javascript .addEventListener isn't working

Tags: javascript

This is probably dumb question, but I'm new in Javascript and I really can't get it.

So I have a bunch of Chart.js graphs on my page and I wanted to add some custom behavior. I made such functions to generate different listeners for different graphs:

```
const listenerPointerUp = (params) =>
    evt => {
        //code
    }
```

and set them up:

```
canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', listenerPointerUp(params));
```

but listeners just weren't working, although they were there in Chrome

until I tried:

```
canvas.onpointerup = listenerPointerUp(params)
```

Then it started working just fine.

I wonder what caused such behavior?

I hope I provided enough data to figure out what was my mistake. I suppose isn't caused by other context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Argument In Event Listener Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434645/pass-argument-in-event-listener-function)

Comment: Everyone is missing the fact it is calling a function and it returns a function.....

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Surely OP means they weren't being called. How else would they not be working

Comment: OP, I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. Could you try a simple example like `canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', () => console.log('test'))` to see if it gets called?

Comment: @KeldanChapman, yes, sorry, that is exactly what I meant. And I did try same simple example, but it wasn't working either. Could it be caused by Chart.js?

Answer (score -2):

You could do the function call like this

```
   canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', function(e) {
      listenerPointerUp(params,e)
    });

    const listenerPointerUp = (params,evt) =>{
        //code
    }
```

> ****working fine****
>
> ```
> canvas.onpointerup = listenerPointerUp(params)
> ```
>
> function call properly assigned with in event

**Why ?**

The function trigger on window load not an event call. And also listener not assigning the function properly for the event

```js
let params = "clicked"
document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', listenerPointerUp(params));

function listenerPointerUp(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<button id="demo">click</button>
```

**Solution**

```js
let params = "clicked"
document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', ()=>listenerPointerUp(params));

function listenerPointerUp(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<button id="demo">click</button>
```

Comment: The `listenerPointerUp` function returns the intended callback function. You shouldn't be wrapping it in another function (ie. `()=>listenerPointerUp(params)`) otherwise nothing will happen (Nothing will call the returned function)

Comment: @KeldanChapman you are correct. But i m not intent to return anything. Just wrapping the function call via ES6 Method

Comment: But that is my point. The `listenerPointerUp` function needs to be invoked immediately, so that it can return the proper callback function, have a look again at the OPs code. If you wrap the function call, then it assigns the anonymous function to the event listener, instead of the intended callback function.

Comment: In other words, `listenerPointerUp` is the callback _generator_, **NOT** the callback.

Comment: @KeldanChapman Thanks Man.. i forget to read  `listenerPointerUp` function. Now updated

Comment: I'm glad you read the function, but you are still wrapping it in a function, so it will still not work...

Comment: @KeldanChapman yes.. but the op passing params to the `listenerPointerUp` function. That why wrapping the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227342/discussion-between-keldan-chapman-and-prasanth).